# How do I know which prediction is for which data? And, how to evaluate prediction?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have the code below that uses an Artificial Neural Network (ANN) to predict a class in a CSV file.

If I want to find the predictions on the test data, do I do the following?

```
    predictions = model.predict(X_test)
    # round predictions
    rounded = [round(x[0]) for x in predictions]
    prediction = pd.DataFrame(rounded,columns=['predictions']).to_csv('prediction.csv')
```

In this case, I will have a CSV file with a list of predictions (0 and 1). My questions are:

- How do I know for which data (row) the prediction is referring?
- How can I find the accuracy of the resulting predictions?

  ```
  import numpy as np 
  import pandas as pd 
  from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, BatchNormalization, Activation
  import keras.models as md
  import keras.layers.core as core
  import keras.utils.np_utils as kutils
  import keras.layers.convolutional as conv

  from keras.layers import MaxPool2D

  from subprocess import check_output
  dataset = pd.read_csv('mutation-train.csv')

  dataset = dataset[['CDS_Mutation',
                     'Primary_Tissue',
                      'Genomic',
                      'Gene_ID',
                      'Official_Symbol',
                      'Histology']]

  X = dataset.iloc[:,0:5].values
  y = dataset.iloc[:,5].values

  # Encoding categorical data
  from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
  labelencoder_X_0 = LabelEncoder()
  X[:, 0] = labelencoder_X_0.fit_transform(X[:, 0])
  labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
  X[:, 1] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, 1])
  labelencoder_X_2= LabelEncoder()
  X[:, 2] = labelencoder_X_2.fit_transform(X[:, 2])
  labelencoder_X_4= LabelEncoder()
  X[:, 4] = labelencoder_X_4.fit_transform(X[:, 4])

  X = X.astype(float)
  labelencoder_y= LabelEncoder()
  y = labelencoder_y.fit_transform(y)

  onehotencoder0 = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
  X = onehotencoder0.fit_transform(X).toarray()
  X = X[:,0:]
  onehotencoder1 = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [1])
  X = onehotencoder1.fit_transform(X).toarray()
  X = X[:,0:]
  onehotencoder2 = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [2])
  X = onehotencoder2.fit_transform(X).toarray()
  X = X[:,0:]
  onehotencoder4 = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [4])
  X = onehotencoder4.fit_transform(X).toarray()
  X = X[:,0:]

  # Splitting the dataset training and test sets
  from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
  X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2)

  # Feature scaling
  from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
  sc = StandardScaler()
  X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
  X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

  # Evaluating the ANN
  from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
  from keras.models import Sequential
  from keras.layers import Dense
  from keras.layers import Dropout

  model=Sequential()
  model.add(Dense(32, activation = 'relu', input_shape=(X.shape[1],)))
  model.add(Dense(16, activation = 'relu'))
  model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
  model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ["accuracy"])

  # Compile model
  model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
  # Fit the model
  model.fit(X,y, epochs=3, batch_size=1)

  # Evaluate the model
  scores = model.evaluate(X,y)
  print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))

  # Calculate predictions
  predictions = model.predict(X)
  prediction = pd.DataFrame(predictions,columns=['predictions']).to_csv('prediction.csv')
  ```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I know for which data (row) the prediction is referring?

The predictions are in a vector of the same length and order as the input.

> How can I find the accuracy of the resulting predictions?

Compare the prediction to the ground truth for your inputs.  Divide correct predictions by size of the input set.

If you don't *have* the ground truth for your input set, then you cannot find the accuracy.  The best you can do is to estimate the accuracy as the final test accuracy at the end of model training.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. The issue is that when I "print X_test", I get a list of values and not the data per se. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add an index column to `dataset`. Then after `train_test_split` recover the new arrangement of indices.